# Telnet Blocking C# TCP Server

Tags: c#, tcp, telnet, asyncsocket

I am writing a TCP server in C#, and have run into a strange and potentially a security issue as well.

My basic arch for accepting new connections is as follows:

1. A C# Socket listening on a port, using the `AcceptAsync` method to accept incoming connections.
2. Spinning off accepted connections using the `ThreadPool` for finishing the accept.

Everything works quite well, however everything grinds to a halt if someone telnets into the port.

Symptoms:

- If I telnet into my server and do not send any data (i.e. do not hit any keys) the server will never finish accepting the connection.
- My `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed` callback is never hit for the telnet connection.
- Even worse, all further connections are blocked/queued and never get accepted by my code.    They are put into a `CLOSE_WAIT` state:

  `TCP    127.0.0.1:8221         chance:53960           CLOSE_WAIT`

  `TCP    127.0.0.1:8221         chance:53962           CLOSE_WAIT`

  `TCP    127.0.0.1:8221         chance:53964           CLOSE_WAIT`

Any advice would be appreciated.

StartAccept:

```
private void StartAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs AcceptArgs)
{
    CurrentAcceptArgs = AcceptArgs;
    AcceptArgs.AcceptSocket = null;

    if (AcceptArgs.Buffer == null ||
        AcceptArgs.Buffer.Length < 1024)
    {
        AcceptArgs.SetBuffer(new byte[1024], 0, 1024);
    }

    if (MainSocket != null)
    {
        lock (MainSocket)
        {
            // If this is false, we have an accept waiting right now, otherwise it will complete aynsc
            if (MainSocket.AcceptAsync(AcceptArgs) == false)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FinishAccept, AcceptArgs);
                StartAccept(GetConnection());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Completed Callback for accepting connections:

```
protected override void OnIOCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    PWClientRemote RemoteClient = e.UserToken as PWClientRemote;

    // Determine which type of operation just completed and call the associated handler.
    switch (e.LastOperation)
    {
        case SocketAsyncOperation.Accept:
            StartAccept(GetConnection());
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FinishAccept, e);
            break;
        default:
            base.OnIOCompleted(sender, e);
            break;
    }
}
```

Finish Accept:

```
private void FinishAccept(object StateObject)
{
    SocketAsyncEventArgs args = (SocketAsyncEventArgs)StateObject;
    FinishAcceptInternal(args);
}
```

Here is the wireshark from connecting telnet but before sending data:

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  1 0.000000    192.168.1.146         192.168.1.109         TCP      66     59766 > 8221 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
  2 0.000076    192.168.1.109         192.168.1.146         TCP      66     8221 > 59766 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
  3 0.000389    192.168.1.146         192.168.1.109         TCP      60     59766 > 8221 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=0
```

This should be the complete handshake to establish my connection, but the `Completed` event is never raised.

Comment: Have you googled on CLOSE_WAIT? If you did, you know why you got it. And where is the code?

Comment: Can you specify a timeout for a connection attempt?

Comment: Yes, I understand that I have connections stuck in a bad TCP state.  I'm looking for solutions.  Currently it is possible for a malicious user to hang my server by simply using telnet to connect to it.

Comment: "If I telnet into my server and do not send any data (i.e. do not hit any keys) the server will never finish accepting the connection"

pause your process when this happens. At which line is it hanging ?

Comment: Technically none of them in my code.  I'm guessing it is stalled somewhere in the framework, though pausing all threads does not give me any more insight.  Pauses on Application.Run().  AcceptAsync is called, and should return Asynchronously when a connection is incoming and call OnIOCompleted with SocketAsyncOperation.Accept.  That does not happen in this case.  It acts as if it begins to accept the connection, but does not get far enough to call back into my code.

Comment: You are locking on MainSocket from different threads, and the code inside the lock does different things based on whether connections are waiting... something smells about your main socket listening code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I found the underlying cause:

The error is this line:

```
if (AcceptArgs.Buffer == null ||
    AcceptArgs.Buffer.Length < 1024)
{
    AcceptArgs.SetBuffer(new byte[1024], 0, 1024);
}
```

This is because if you set a buffer, AcceptAsync will block until it receives some data.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.acceptasync.aspx):

> The minimum buffer size required is 288 bytes. If a larger buffer size is specified, then the Socket will expect some extra data other than the address data received by the Winsock AcceptEx call and will wait until this extra data is received.

My corrected code:

```
// We set a null buffer here.
// If we set a valid buffer, the accept will expect data
// and will hang unless it gets it.
AcceptArgs.SetBuffer(null, 0, 0);
```

I'm not sure if this is the exact correct fix, setting a buffer of 288 bytes or smaller did not seem to correct the issue.  Only setting the buffer to null caused the `Completed` event to be raised when connecting without sending data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GetConnection is blocked somewhere.
Usually if server is not under heavy load asynchronous operations may complete in synchronous manner.
Also the fact that AcceptAsync returned false or callback method was called means that asynchronous operation is complete and your code should analyse the results.

Below is a simple asynchronous TCP server skeleton that accepts connections asynchronously.

```
void StartServer()
{
    Socket serverSocket = new Socket(addr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(addr, port));
    s.Listen(5000);

    SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(AcceptCompleted);
    args.UserToken = serverSocket;

    if ( !serverSocket.AcceptAsync(args) )
        AcceptCompleted(this, args);
}

void AcceptCompleted(object obj, SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
{
    Socket client = args.AcceptSocket;
    if (args.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
        return;

    StartClientOperations(args.AcceptSocket);

    args.AcceptSocket = null;
    Socket s = (Socket)args.UserToken;
    if (!s.AcceptAsync(args))
        AcceptCompleted(this, args);
}

void StartClientOperations(Socket newClient) 
{
    //start other asynchronous operations here with the client socket
}
```

Comment: GetConnection() happens before the TCP connection is made.  It is also just a link to a simple connection pool queue.

Comment: In your code GetConnection was called after actual TCP connection was accepted. Can you elaborate more about simple connection pool queue and what its role on your application?